# Modify twig node

Tags: php, twig

I'd like to modify template blocks, after (or during) rendering for all templates but I also need to know the name of each template and the block.

Consider these two templates:

```
//master.twig
{% block hello %}
{% endblock %}

//and page.twig
{% extends 'master.twig' %}
{% block hello %}

{% endblock %}

$twig->render('page.twig');
```

After (or during) this, I'd like to change the content.

Pseudo-code:

```
$template->blocks['master.twig']['hello'] .= 'append something';
```

How can this be done?

## update

Looks like `Twig_NodeVisitorInterface`'s can be used to modify nodes effortlessly.

However, to get the name of the current template, I subclassed `Twig_Environment` like so:

```
class TwigEnvironment extends \Twig_Environment
{

    protected $currentTemplateName = null;

    public function compileSource($source, $name = null)
    {
        $this->currentTemplateName = $name;
        return parent::compileSource($source, $name);
    }

    public function getCurrentTemplateName()
    {
        return $this->currentTemplateName;
    }

}
```

Looks like this will work!

Comment: You can search for "NodeVisitor" to get the answer. Sorry i'm on the road right now, can't help more now.

Comment: Ok. I haven't looked at that yet, will do now. Thanks.

Comment: Hm. This looks interesting, but it doesn't look like the NodeVisitor is given any information about the actual template?

Comment: Yes, `NodeVisitors` are used to interact on compilers... The compiler can access the template context, but not the node itself. Anyway, this is the responsibility of the `Twig_Loader` to get Twig contents from a file path (or a NoSQL key, a database id, ...) so by design, you can't have lots of information about it elsewhere. You can eventually try, from a NodeVisitor, `$template = $env->getCompiler()->getFilename()` but I'm very unsure about the result.